# Missing Foreign string characters in sqlExecute() queries

Tags: r, rodbc

we needed to fetch data from our database to R directly, we employed sqlExecute(). However, because our string columns contain escape letters such as “ş”, “ö”, “ğ” (Turkish characters which don’t exist in US-Char codes), these characters left missing in my query outputs. Do you know any arguments for sqlExecute() to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your R locales at the very least and possible set your system locale to allow the use of valid codes and fonts. Since you have provided none of the details of your system and applications, specific advice is not possible. Read `?locales` which does say that setting this in R should be honored by your system facilities but that exceptions have been observed.

Here's further information from: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales

```
cat(hdr)
package_name    lang_name   locale  localewin   localewincharset
> cat(trk)
tr_utf8 Turkish tr_TR.UTF-8 Turkish_Turkey.1254 WINDOWS-1254
```

Comment: I am also using SPSS Modeler 18.1, because it's configuration requires me to set local setting in US standards, I think it conflicts with our database which is in Turkish settings. If its possible only to change R's locale settings, then I hope, that will solve my problem. Here is my R system locale properties;[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252